# How to find lengths of words and return them as array?

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the lengths of words in an array of strings and return another array that contains that number of lengths.

For example, the input of

```
["Dragon Lore", "Howl", "Empress"]
```

would return

```
[11, 4, 7].
```

I have typedef structs that define arrays of both strings and integers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_string_array {
    int size;
    char** array;
} string_array;

typedef struct s_integer_array {
    int size;
    int* array;
} integer_array;
```

The function that would find lengths of words I tried to implement looks as follows:

```
integer_array* my_count_on_it(string_array* param_1) {

    int arrSize = param_1->size;
    integer_array *strLens = malloc(arrSize*sizeof(integer_array));

    strLens->array = malloc(arrSize*sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){
        strLens->array[i] = strlen(param_1->array[i]);
    }

    return strLens;
}
```

When it is tested in the terminal using 3rd party tests it shows that `Return value: []`.

Regarding test cases, I did not come up with my own ones.

Comment: Could you show us also how `param_1->size;` is calculated?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Sadly, I did not come up with own test cases. Thus, didn't write anything worth in main.

Comment: you need `strLens->size = arrSize;` ... also verify that `malloc()` did not return `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `strLens->size = arrSize;`